# Does Hedera apply a token association fee when an account is configured for automatic token association?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I have a question about Hedera token associations. I understand that there's a token association fee for manually associating tokens with an account, but I'm unsure if this fee is also applied when the account is configured for automatic token association.

I couldn't find any documentation confirming whether or not a fee is charged for automatic token associations. Can someone please clarify if the token association fee is applied in this case? Any reference to the relevant documentation would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is Yes but the fee is changed when the account owners configure their account `MaxAutomaticTokenAssociations`. The account owners can configure their account `MaxAutomaticTokenAssociations` up to 1000 tokens and pays the fee upfront. Please take a look at this [link](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/sdks-and-apis/deprecated/sdks/cryptocurrency/update-an-account) for more information.

In summary, the associate fee will not apply at the the time the association take place but it applies at the time of configuration.